# Switching from Illuminate\Html to Collective\Html, Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

I updated `composer.json` to remove illuminate\html and add:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
```

I removed the providers/aliases from `app.php` for Illuminate\Html and added the replacements:

```
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

...

```
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

However when running `composer update` I receive the output:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Removing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)

- Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.1.4)
  Downloading: 100%  

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 648

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found                                                     

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]                                                                   
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 648
```

I tried updating `composer.json` scripts as suggested here: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/54

But I'm still receiving the error.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the end I managed to fix this with some help on IRC (thanks sisve) and these commands. First I rolled back to a working site with illuminate/html. Then:

```
composer dumpautoload
composer clearcache
php artisan clear-compiled
```

If the `clear-compiled` fails then make sure there are no references to Illuminate\Html in `bootstrap/cache/config.php` and run it again.

Remove all references to Illuminate\Html in `config/app.php` 
Remove the `illuminate/html` require in `composer.json`

```
composer update
```

Add the laravelcollective/html package as described here: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation

```
composer update
```