# Converting Laravel from Illuminate to Laravel Collective HTML

Tags: php, laravel

I am in the process of learning Laravel, currently, I have a Template/Framework installed on the server and it uses the Illuminate framework? I have read that Laravel has depreciated that package with Laravel.

What is the process of updating an existing template from Illuminate to the more current Collective HTML?

When I try it breaks the pages existing. I have tried the following but it does not seem to help.

[Switching from Illuminate\Html to Collective\Html, Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283767/switching-from-illuminate-html-to-collective-html-class-illuminate-html-htmlse)

Comment: Sounds like you have to remove the old service provider and facade paths in config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing a duplicate Illuminate statement in the config/app.php as hinted at by Rob Fonseca.